# Magnetic field inside a current carrying wire

Tags: electromagnetism

Assume an infinite wire carrying DC current. According to Ampere's force law， the moving electrons inside the wire are influenced by the Lorenz force pointing to the center. As a result, the current distribution is changed and finally all current flows in the center.

My question is, what is wrong with the above analysis? Are there other forces on the electrons for balancing so the uniform current distribution can be sustained?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the usual picture of a *uniform* current density is a mathematical idealization. Realistically, electrons will accumulate near the axis of the wire in such a way as to create an outward pointing electric field that negates this effect. The equilibrium current distribution will no longer be uniform.

Alternatively, one might approximate a uniform distribution by replacing the wire by many parallel thin wires, each one insulated from the others.

Comment: It seems a good explanation. Do you have any references like papers or articles on this? Just curious. Thanks

Comment: None that come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

The generalization of Ohm's law in the presence of a magnetic field is $\overrightarrow{j}=\gamma (\overrightarrow{E}+{{R}_{H}}\overrightarrow{j}\wedge \overrightarrow{B})$ with ${{R}_{H}}$ the Hall constant. In practice, in a good conductor $\gamma {{R}_{H}}B\ll 1$, and the effect is weak.

If we want to take it into account, it seems to me that we can keep the current density uniform and unchanged $\overrightarrow{j}={{j}_{z}}\overrightarrow{{{e}_{z}}}$ but simply assume the existence of a radial electric field such that ${{E}_{r}}\overrightarrow{{{e}_{r}}}+{{R}_{H}}{{j}_{z}}\overrightarrow{{{e}_{z}}}\wedge B\overrightarrow{{{e}_{\theta }}}=\overrightarrow{0}$ or ${{E}_{r}}=+{{R}_{H}}{{j}_{z}}B$.

By using, $\overrightarrow{\nabla }\centerdot \overrightarrow{E}=\rho /{{\varepsilon }_{0}}$ one would find a weak density of charge within the conductor.

So to conclude, it would be : uniform current density, an unmodified magnetic field but a conductor slightly charged volume. If someone can confirm or explain why this is false  ?

Comment: I can understand that the magnetic field effect is weak. But what I worried about is no matter how weak it is, given enough length of the wire, the distribution will eventually be changed, unless other forces come in. And your theory is the small static charges and the induced electrostatic field. That could be an answer I guess. Thanks